# How to run a MPI task?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, mpi

I am newbie in Linux and recently started working with our university super-computer and I need to install my program ( [GAMESS Quantum Chemistry Software](http://www.msg.ameslab.gov/gamess/) ) on my own allocated space. I have installed and ran it successfully under 'sockets' but actually I need to run it under 'mpi' ( otherwise there will be little advantage of using a super-computer ).

System Setting:

- OS:  Linux64 , Redhat, intel
- MPI: impi
- compiler: ifort
- modules:  slurm ,  intel/intel-15.0.1 , intel/impi-15.0.1

This software runs ' rungms ' and receives arguments as:

**rungms [fileName][Version][CPU count ]**  ( for example: ./rungms Opt 00 4 )

Here is my bash file ( my feeling is this is the main culprit for my problem !):

```
#!/bin/bash

#Based off of Monte's Original Script for Torque:
#https://gist.github.com/mlunacek/6306340#file-matlab_example-pbs

#These are SBATCH directives specifying name of file, queue, the
#Quality of Service, wall time, Node Count, #of CPUS, and the
#destination output file (which appends node hostname and JobID)

#SBATCH -J OptMPI
#SBATCH --qos janus-debug
#SBATCH -t 00-00:10:00
#SBATCH -N2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH -o output-OptMPI-%N-JobID-%j

#NOTE: This Module Will Be Replaced With Slurm Specific:
module load intel/impi-15.0.1

mpirun /projects/augenda/gamess/rungms Opt 00 2 > OptMPI.out
```

As I said before, the program is compiled for mpi ( and not 'sockets' ) .

My problem is when I run run **sbatch Opt.sh**  , I receive this error:

- **srun: error: PMK_KVS_Barrier duplicate request from task 1**
- **when I change -N number , sometimes I receive error saying (4 !=2
  )**.
- with odd number of -N I receive error saying it expects even number of processes.

What am I missing ?

[Here is the code from our super-computer website as a bash file example](https://www.rc.colorado.edu/node/511)

Comment: I would really recommend to ask the supercomputer support https://www.rc.colorado.edu/support for advice. There is too much information missing for us and my experience with SC support in other institutions was always quite good.

Comment: @VladimirF Actually that's what I did multiple times but their answer is always : we dont offer help in software installation !  I know in some other states you can just walk in and ask them to install your softwares but it never happens here !  I don't know why they expect a chemist to be such a professional linux coder ?!! That's why I desperately need help from here.

Comment: How do you run it? When you get `4 != 2` are you sure you specify the right number of cpus also in the `rungms` parameter?

Comment: @VladimirF After loading the 3 modules ( slurm , intel , impi ) and requesting an allocation ( salloc --qos janus- debug ) , I navigate to the folder containing Opt.sh and run sbatch Opt.sh.

Answer (score 2):

The Slurm Workload Manager has a few ways of invoking an Intel MPI process. Likely, all you have to do is use `srun` rather than `mpirun` in your case. If errors are still present, refer [here](https://slurm.schedmd.com/mpi_guide.html#intel_mpi) for alternative ways to invoke Intel MPI jobs; it's rather dependent on how the HPC admins configured the system.